# Powershell SQLCMD

Tags: sql, powershell, batch-file, sqlcmd

We were experiencing problems with Powershell and SQLCMD, when there was sapces in the -v parameter variable powershell wouldn't run the command.

e.g.

```
sqlcmd ... -v VAR="Some space"
```

Has anyone experienced this before or know how to fix the problem?

Thanks,

B

Comment: have you tried a %20 instead of the space?

Comment: If you're using SQL 2008, I highly recommend using Invoke-SqlCmd instead (along with the other cmdlets & providers).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714054/how-to-execute-sqlcmd-from-powershell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax above works for the PS commandline but fails within a script.

We struggled a long time with how to make this work.  One of our very clever QA guys finally came up with the following:

````
$variableWithSpaces="one two three"
$mySqlCmd = "sqlcmd -E -S $dbServer -i $script  -v var=```"$variableWithSpaces```" "
Invoke-Expression $mySqlCmd
````

Plug ugly but it works.

Comment: Tried for 4+ hours, even building commands that looked great in echoargs but still failed. This finally did it. PSH rocks <s>.

Answer (score 2):

Powershell will actually pass the parameter to the program as `"VAR=Some space"`. Maybe sqlcmd stumbles over this. By using

```
VAR=`"Some space`"
```

instead it will get passed as `VAR="Some space"`. Maybe that resolves the problem.