# How to execute sqlcmd from powershell?

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I have a string in powershell, which contains a native sqlcmd command. The command itself can be executed successfully in cmd.exe. I have difficulty in executing them in powershell. Anyone can help? Thanks.

This is sql.sql

```
select @@servername
go
select @@servicename
```

This is the result when I execute the sqlcmd command from cmd.exe

```
C:\Users\test>sqlcmd -S "(local)\instance1" -U a -P a -i "c:\temp\sql.sql"

--------------------------------------------------
thesimpsons\INSTANCE1

(1 rows affected)

--------------------------------------------------
INSTANCE1

(1 rows affected)

C:\Users\test>
```

This is the powershell script to call the sqlcmd command.

```
$sql = @"
sqlcmd -S "(local)\instance1" -U a -P a -i "c:\temp\sql.sql"
"@

Invoke-Command $sql
```

When I execute this powershell script, I got the following error.

```
PS C:\TEMP> $sql = @"
sqlcmd -S "(local)\instance1" -U a -P a -i "c:\temp\sql.sql"
"@

Invoke-Command $sql
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parame
ters.
At line:5 char:15
+ Invoke-Command <<<<  $sql
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBin 
   dingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands 
   .InvokeCommandCommand
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015038/powershell-sqlcmd

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To call a Win32 executable you want to use the call operator `&` like this:

```
& sqlcmd -S "(local)\instance1" -U a -P a -i "c:\temp\sql.sql"
```

Answer (score 20):

You could also stop using the external 'SQLCMD.EXE' and use the [Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/cc281720%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd is a SQL Server cmdlet that runs scripts that contain statements from the languages (Transact-SQL and XQuery) and commands that are supported by the sqlcmd utility

Just open the 'sqlps' utility and run

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\temp\sql.sql"
```

Please see [Running SQL Server PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/cc281962%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

You can also load the SQL Server snap-ins manually in PowerShell before using 'Invoke-Sqlcmd';
for MS SQL Server 2012 you can do that by running
`Import-Module SqlPs`

Comment: While Andi Arismendi's answer is a good one, and directly answers executing of the sqlcmd executable, I believe this one should be the accepted answer. If you're running sqlcmd scripts through powershell, it will save you time, effort, and keystrokes to simply use Invoke-Sqlcmd.

Comment: 1. Invoke-Sqlcmd doesn't implement all the commands that are available with SQLCMD. 
2. Invoke-Sqlcmd is not included in the base Powershell install

Comment: Invoke-Sqlcmd adds a semicolon to the end of stored procedures, which causes issues with comparison tools. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/74d8acd4-9788-48e5-93bc-fa165a573ee2/powershell-invokesqlcmd-adding-semicolon?forum=sqltools and https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/5v29o2/options_for_executing_sql_server_script/

Comment: Not to mention, Invoke-Sqlcmd wasn't supported in Powershell 2.0.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I build some externals command in my scripts

```
$scriptblock = {fullpath\sqlcmd -S `"(local)\instance1`" <# comment option -S #>`
                                -U a `
                                -P a `
                                -i `"c:\temp\sql.sql`" }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

You can then use $args variable inside it and even start it remotly.

```
$scriptblock = {fullpath\sqlcmd -S `"(local)\instance1`" <# comment option -S #>`
                                -U a `
                                -P a `
                                -i `"$($args[0])`" }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -argumentList "c:\temp\sql.sql" -computer "remote1"
```

**Remark :**

This allow to comment each param.

Be careful not to forget a "`" and no space after them where they are at the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Invoke-Expression` rather than `Invoke-Command`

Comment: I don't see why people try to use Invoke-Expression when calling Win32 executables... This is what the call operator is for.

Comment: @Andy - Invoke-Expression allows you to generate the entire command as a string first, which could be useful depending upon the circumstances. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604089/dynamically-generate-command-line-command-then-invoke-using-powershell

Comment: Yep, but that's not happening here. Only use Invoke-Expression when there is an expression that needs to be evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

The first positional parameter of invoke-command is -scriptblock, and it expects a script block argument. To take advantage of a here-string to build the command and then run it with invoke-command, you need to convert the here-string to a script block:

```
$sql = @"
sqlcmd -S "(local)\instance1" -U a -P a -i "c:\temp\sql.sql"
 "@

 Invoke-Command ([scriptblock]::create($sql))
```

Comment: All this is going to do is return the value in $sql, it will not actually execute it (at least not on my machine).

Answer (score 0):

Both instance name and username should be fully qualified

`<domain_name>\Instanc_name` and `<domai_name>\Username`. Only your instance name is correctly scripted.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me for using sqlcmd from within the powershell script using the & operator, see sample to generate a csv file:

> & cmd /c "sqlcmd -S $sv  -i $PROCFILE -s, -v varDB = $dbclean -o $filename"

`$sv` has server name like `SERVERNAME\INSTANCE`

`$PROCFILE` is like `d:\TSTSQL\Sqlquery.SQL`

`$filename` is `d:\TSTSQL\Desiredoutfilename.CSV`

`$dbclean` is a parameter passed to the sql file