# How to bind the -v parameter of sqlcmd from a PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

The following code, setting the -v parameter directly is working

```
$sqlcmd = @(Resolve-Path "$env:ProgramFiles\Microsoft SQL Server\*\Tools\binn\SQLCMD.EXE")[0]

$path1 = 'D:\somescript.sql'

& $sqlcmd -b -S NB-BK\SQLEXPRESS -d BK_Prod -U sa -P mypassword -l 180 -i $path1 -v Mandant=1 SAPMandant="009" SAPEinrichtung="0001"
```

But I need a way to set these values from a PowerShell variable.

I tried:

```
$sqlcmd = @(Resolve-Path "$env:ProgramFiles\Microsoft SQL Server\*\Tools\binn\SQLCMD.EXE")[0]

$path1 = 'D:\somescript.sql'

$sqlcmdparameters = 'Mandant=1 SAPMandant="009" SAPEinrichtung="0001" '
& $sqlcmd -b -S NB-BK\SQLEXPRESS -d BK_Prod -U sa -P mypassword -l 180 -i $path1 -v $sqlcmdparameters
```

I found this [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714054/how-to-execute-sqlcmd-from-powershell), but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using start-process. That's what I do for Powershell command-line parsing issues. First try invoke operator (&) and if that doesn't work wrap it in a start-process call.

```
$tempFile = [io.path]::GetTempFileName()

$exitCode = (start-process -FilePath $sqlcmd -ArgumentList @"
-b -S NB-BK\SQLEXPRESS -d BK_Prod -U sa -P mypassword -l 180 -i $path1 -v $sqlcmdparameters
"@ -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput $tempFile -NoNewWindow -Passthru).ExitCode
```

When using start-process typically you'll need to capture exitcode and also redirect output to temp file in get back the results. I'll then have some code to check $exitcode and cleanup temp file in try/catch/finally block

Comment: +1 for a solution that works. I accept your answer, because it shows how to use a string with all the parameter mapping. I found a more direct solution to the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following solution **for PowerShell V2**

```
$sqlcmd = @(Resolve-Path "$env:ProgramFiles\Microsoft SQL Server\*\Tools\binn\SQLCMD.EXE")[0]
$path1 = 'D:\somescript.sql'
$cmdparameters = @(
    'Mandant=1',
    'SAPMandant="009"'
)

& $sqlcmd -b -S NB-BK\SQLEXPRESS -d BK_Prod -U sa -P mypassword -l 180 -i $path1 -v $cmdparameters
```

Comment: Interesting passing an array works. Calling legacy commands in V1/V2 get's better in Powershell V3 with the -% operator. Keith Hill has blog post with sqlcmd -v example using V3's -% operator: http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/powershell-v3-ctp2-provides-better-argument-passing-to-exes/