# sqlcmd -v parameter ignored in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd, powershell-5.0

I've read the documentation ([sqlcmd Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)), but I can't get `sqlcmd`'s `-v` parameter to work as expected.

Assuming this SQL script (echo.sql):

```
:setvar THE_PATH C:\Users\Craig\Desktop
PRINT 'THE_PATH: $(THE_PATH)'

:setvar THE_TOP 10
PRINT 'THE_TOP: $(THE_TOP)'
```

When run at the PowerShell prompt without the `-v` argument set:

```
PS> sqlcmd -E -S 'server' -d 'database' -i '.\echo.sql'
THE_PATH: C:\Users\Craig\Desktop
THE_TOP: 10
```

Setting the numeric variable (`THE_TOP`) are ignored:

```
PS> sqlcmd -E -S 'server' -d 'database' -i '.\echo.sql' -v THE_TOP=5

PS> sqlcmd -E -S 'server' -d 'database' -i '.\echo.sql'
THE_PATH: C:\Users\Craig\Desktop
THE_TOP: 10
```

If I eliminate the default value for `THE_TOP` in `echo.sql`, it reinforced the assertion that the parameter is being ignored:

```
:setvar THE_TOP
PRINT 'THE_TOP: $(THE_TOP)'

PS> sqlcmd -E -S 'server' -d 'database' -i '.\echo.sql' -v THE_TOP=5
THE_PATH: C:\Users\Craig\Desktop
THE_TOP: $(THE_TOP)
```

If I attempt to set the `THE_PATH` parameter, I get:

```
PS> sqlcmd -E -S 'server' -d 'database' -i '.\echo.sql' -v THE_PATH="C:\path"
Sqlcmd: ':\path': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

What is the correct `-v` syntax?

Comment: you're better off using the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet. If you don't want to, pass an array to the `-v` parameter as described in the not accepted answer of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120106/how-to-bind-the-v-parameter-of-sqlcmd-from-a-powershell

Comment: Try ``-v THE_PATH=`"C:\path`"``.

Comment: Neither approach works.

Comment: When you say that something didn't work, you have to say _how_ it didn't work. (Remember, we can't see your screen.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is retarded.

If `:setvar` is used in the script:

```
:setvar THE_TOP
PRINT 'THE_TOP: $(THE_TOP)'
```

then you attempt to set it at the PowerShell prompt, you'll get an error:

```
PS> sqlcmd -E -S server -d database -i .\echo.sql -v THE_TOP=5
'THE_TOP' scripting variable not defined.
```

However, if you DO NOT set it in the script:

```
-- variable disabled
-- :setvar THE_PATH
PRINT 'THE_TOP: $(THE_TOP)'
```

then you attempt to set it at the PowerShell prompt, then it will work as (not really) expected:

```
PS> sqlcmd -E -S server -d database -i .\echo.sql -v THE_TOP=5
THE_TOP: 5
```

** edit **

To supply a dynamically-generated path as a parameter to a script file (extract.sql):

```
:out $(THE_PATH)\extract.csv
SELECT  *
FROM    the_table
WHERE   the_key = $(THE_ID)
...
```

Execute in PowerShell session:

```
PS> $cd = Get-Location
PS> sqlcmd -E -S 'server' -d 'database' -i '.\extract.sql' -v THE_ID=5 THE_PATH=`"$cd\build`"
```